# TensorFlow save model UnimplementedError

Tags: tensorflow, model, kaggle, tpu

I was using Kaggle TPUs to train a TensorFlow model and saving it
here is the model code

```
with strategy.scope():
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape = [None, None, 3]),
    keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(224, 224),
    keras.applications.Xception(
    include_top=False,
    weights="imagenet",
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    ),
    keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dense(64),
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation = 'softmax')
])
```

after training the model I just change the last layer

```
model_sub = keras.models.Sequential( [keras.layers.Input([None, None, 3])] + 
model.layers[:-1] + [tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=-1), name='embedding_norm')])
```

Now when I save the model using the following code

```
model_sub.save('saved_model/xception')
```

The above line gives me the following error

```
UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: 'saved_model/xception/variables/variables_temp/part-00000-of-00001')
    Encountered when executing an operation using EagerExecutor. This error cancels all future operations and poisons their output tensors.
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Kaggle TPU (still) uses [TPU Node](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/system-architecture-tpu-vm#tpu-node) architecture, for which user VM communicates with a remote TPU host over gRPC.

You can use [tf.saved_model.LoadOptions](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/LoadOptions) with `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions="/job:localhost"` to save/restorer a TPU model on local file system:

```
model_dir = "saved_model/xception"

localhost_save_option = tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(experimental_io_device="/job:localhost")
model.save(model_dir, options=localhost_save_option)

# Restore the weights
model2 = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_dir, options=localhost_save_option)
```

For [TPU VM](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/system-architecture-tpu-vm#tpu-vm) you have direct (root) access to the TPU host and can directly save the model on a local drive with:

```
model_sub.save('saved_model/xception')
```